# Multiple AND OR statements in php MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

It seems there's something wrong with this. I don't get any distinct errors, but it's simply not doing what its supposed to be doing. I'm leaning towards there being a problem with the OR statements, but I've put the username in parenth, and the id slots in parenth, and neither work. Honestly, i'm only posting this here because five hours of looking at it got to be enough for me. 
Hopefully something looks blatantly wrong and it's not somewhere else in the code :/

```
$fetch_userone_idslots = mysql_query("SELECT id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4, id_5, id_6 FROM users WHERE id_1 = '$battle_id' || id_2 = '$battle_id || id_3 = '$battle_id || id_4 = '$battle_id || id_5 = '$battle_id || id_6 = '$battle_id && username == '$user_logged_in'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_userone_idslots)){
$useroneidslot_1 = $row['id_1'];
$useroneidslot_2 = $row['id_2'];
$useroneidslot_3 = $row['id_3'];
$useroneidslot_4 = $row['id_4'];
$useroneidslot_5 = $row['id_5'];
$useroneidslot_6 = $row['id_6'];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Reading the error message mysql provides is the first step to more knowledge and understanding. Its kinda sad you need a peer review of your code to find out about an error mysql already tells you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a `==` which does not exist in MySQL. Use just `=`. You can simplify your query like this

```
SELECT id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4, id_5, id_6 FROM users
WHERE '$battle_id' in (id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4, id_5, id_6) 
and username = '$user_logged_in'
```

Comment: Use can use `!=` in MySQL. But normally `<>` is used.

Comment: Both `<>` and `!=` may be used. See [Operator 'not equal'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Answer (score 1):

in `MySQL` you need to use `AND` or `OR` not `||` and `&&`. and one more thing there is no `==`, use only `=`.

```
SELECT id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4, id_5, id_6 
FROM users 
WHERE (
      id_1 = '$battle_id' OR 
      id_2 = '$battle_id' OR  
      id_3 = '$battle_id' OR 
      id_4 = '$battle_id' OR  
      id_5 = '$battle_id' OR  
      id_6 = '$battle_id'
      ) AND 
      username = '$user_logged_in'
```

Comment: Wrong for `||` and `&&`. See [Logical operators in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/logical-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Don't use `==` if you need an eqation. In SQL `==` is just `=`. SQL is differnet that C, it's a query language and syntax is different because it's used for different puprose. My advice is to follow the SQL sintax to avoid similar mistakes.

Comment: Wrong for `||` and `&&`. See [Logical operators in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/logical-operators.html)

Comment: yes but there is no `==` it is just `=` in equations. It is better to follow the correct SQL syntax even `||` and `&&` may work in MySQL. As you see followng this wrong way the guy is used `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Your answer is wrong because it says `||` and `&&` may not be used in MySQL. Update your answer to make it more clear by clicking 'edit'.

Comment: @Jocelyn, my friend, my answer is half right and half wrong - do you think `==` could be used in SQL expression? If you prefer the wrong part - it is ok for me - but following the SQL standart is better than the concreate implementation in MySQL. I will edit my answer, but giving the guy a feeling that SQL is C like language will reflect on understanding of SQL and it is not a good idea. Any way that's not my problem :)